# Why LyX adds intendent on each new line?

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX with Hebrew. For some reason, when I write simple phrases in `standard` mode, it gives the following result:

[image]

Fore some reason it adds intendent from the second phrase. I could tolerate it but the result is:

[image]

How one should solve such issue?

I'll also add the following image which shows that I use the `standard` mode and no listing:

[image]

**EDIT**: I found out that if you press `Ctrl+a+r` it will put it in the right way:

[image]

It is a workaround I could use but I still want to fix this bug. The strange thing is that it worked in the previous LyX version. Maybe I need to change something in the settings?

Comment: Whenever you press "return" you are creating a new paragraph. If you want a new line without a new paragraph, press "ctrl + return". Does that do what you want?

Comment: It does help (although it does not work if you have centered equation and then a new paragraph). But now I found out that if you press `Ctrl+a+r` it will put it in the right (I'll update the question). It is a workaround but I still want to fix this bug. The strange thing is that it worked in the previous version.

Comment: What is the old LyX version where this worked? Does the bug happen if you view a document you created with the old LyX version? Or does it appear only when you create a new document?

Comment: New version: `2.3.5-1`. Old version: `2.2.3`. It happens when I open the new LyX and write a new document. I don't open old documents in the new version.

Comment: good to know. Can you see if it happens when you are writing in a language other than Hebrew? What operating system are you on? Do you by chance have 2.2.3 still installed (I'm guessing not, but if you do it might be helpful)? At this point it would probably be a good idea if you opened a trac ticket on https://www.lyx.org/trac and summarized the information here. Please add the keyword "regression". This word means that it worked in a previous version of LyX but not in a newer version, and implies a high priority. On the ticket, please also post a minimal example .lyx file.

Comment: I have a new laptop and I have installed the newer version so I don't the old one installed. It happens also in other languages. I use LyX on Windows.

Comment: Good to know. In that case best to post a minimal example .lyx on the trac ticket in English, since otherwise it might be thought it is an issue specific to Hebrew.